# How do I apply an index vector over a list of vectors?

Tags: r, list, indexing

I want to apply a long index vector (50+ non-sequential integers) to a long list of vectors (50+ character vectors containing 100+ names) in order to retrieve specific values (as a list, vector, or data frame).

A simplified example is below:

```
> my.list <- list(c("a","b","c"),c("d","e","f"))
> my.index <- 2:3
```

Desired Output

```
[[1]]
[1] "b"
[[2]]
[1] "f"
##or
[1] "b"
[1] "f"
##or
[1] "b" "f"
```

I know I can get the same value from each element using:

```
> lapply(my.list, function(x) x[2])
##or
> lapply(my.list,'[', 2)
```

I can pull the second and third values from each element by:

```
> lapply(my.list,'[', my.index)
[[1]]
[1] "b" "c"

[[2]]
[1] "e" "f"

##or
> for(j in my.index) for(i in seq_along(my.list)) print(my.list[[i]][[j]])
[1] "b"
[1] "e"
[1] "c"
[1] "f"
```

I don't know how to pull just the one value from each element.

I've been looking for a few days and haven't found any examples of this being done, but it seems fairly straight forward.  Am I missing something obvious here?

Thank you,
Scott

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you have a problem that is like `lapply` but involves multiple parallel lists/vectors, consider `Map` or `mapply` (`Map` simply being a wrapper around `mapply` with `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` hardcoded).

Try this:

```
Map("[",my.list,my.index)
#[[1]]
#[1] "b"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "f"
```

..or:

```
mapply("[",my.list,my.index)
#[1] "b" "f"
```